# Adding UUID to Nginx log

Tags: nginx

I need to have a unique identifier on each Nginx log line. Is there a easy way to add this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can assemble an UUID from [nginx variables](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#Variables) you can use [log_format](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=format) to add it to the log.

One common way to do that is to add an HTTP header with the UUID and capture it on nginx (it exposes all headers as `$http_<header_name>` variables) to add to the custom log format.

Answer (score 4):

Either upgrade to nginx >= 1.11, which supports [`$request_id`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_id) variable.

Or for older versions you can use Perl module for generating UUID, in `http` section of `nginx.conf` (or `conf.d/uuid.conf`):

```
perl_require "Data/UUID.pm";
perl_set $request_id 'sub {
   my $ug = new Data::UUID;
   return $ug->create_str();
}';
```

On Debian you'll need `nginx-extra` package (Perl scripting in nginx) and `libossp-uuid-perl`:

```
sudo apt install nginx-extra libossp-uuid-perl
```

Then you can append `$request_id` to log or set HTTP header:

```
proxy_set_header Request-Id $request_id
```

Answer (score 3):

`$connection` variable contains connection identifier. It's not globally unique, I guess it will start from 0 after Nginx restart. But it should be unique between the restarts.